# ng-repeat showing multiple buttons

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using ng-repeat like this, where product is an object I am getting from backend, but the problem is that instead of single update,delete button to be shown in one row, it is showing 5-6 rows. I know the spacing is not proper but right now i am focused only on the functionality of the button

```js
{ 
  "code": 200, 
  "message": "Products retreived successfully", 
  "params": null, 
  "data": { 
    "controller": "ProductController", 
    "method": "view_all_product", 
    "result": [ 
      { 
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "abc", 
        "description": "def", 
        "price": 12, 
        "image": "qw", 
        "tags": "er", 
        "partner_id": "2" 
       } 
    ] 
  } 
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="obj in product">
        <td>{{obj.data.result.id}}</td>
        <td>{{obj.data.result.name}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="update()">Update</button></td>
        <td><button ng-click="delete()">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: What does `product` look like? Can you show us a sample of the data structure? If your object has 5-6 properties then, `ngRepeat` will create 5-6 rows.

Comment: yes the product has 6 properties..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you are passing to the `ngRepeat` directive has 6 properties, so you will get 6 rows. That is how `ngRepeat` works. If you only want to repeat once for each object in the `result` array then that should be the what you pass to `ngRepaet`:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="obj in product.data.result">
        <td>{{obj.id}}</td>
        <td>{{obj.name}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="update()">Update</button></td>
        <td><button ng-click="delete()">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```